# What is wrong with this recursive code?

Tags: c++, recursion, stack-overflow

I am doing online work using CodeLab for C++ and am not sure what's wrong with my code. Here is the question:

Write a recursive, int-valued function, len, that accepts a string and returns the number of characters in the string. 
 The length of a string is: 
0 if the string is the empty string (""). 
1 more than the length of the rest of the string beyond the first character.

And here's my code:

```
int len(string s)
{
  if (s.length()==0)
    return 0;
 else
 {
    return 1+(len(s)-1);
 }
}
```

It says I have a run-time error.
Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt that the assignment wants you to use an `std::string`. It looks more like it wants you to manually determine the length of a `const char*` string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well here:

```
     return 1+(len(s)-1);
```

The length of the string never decreases. So you will eventually have a stackoverflow because you never hit your base case `(s.length() == 0).` You need to get a substring where the length of s decreases by 1:

```
     return 1+(len(s.erase(0,1))); // erases 1 char from beginning then recurses
```

Hopefully this is purely academic, because `std::string` has a `length` method that will run in constant time. (Not to mention erasing from the front of a string is probably horribly inefficient-- see the other answers that work with `char *`)

Comment: Damn it... my boss swung by and I had to stop typing... +1 :D

Comment: I see what you are saying, but it says "1 more than the length of the rest of the string beyond the first character", how do I interpret this?

Comment: A stackoverflow.  How apropo!

Answer (score 3):

len(s) will never decrease and cause a stackoverflow. I would do something like:

```
int len(const char * s) {
    if(*s == '\0')
        return 0;
    else
        return 1 + len(s+1); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are never modifying `s` in your code, so if `s` is not empty you keep calling the same function and again, with the same parameter; your never stop. Your computer runs out of stack space and the program crashes.

Others have given you some ideas/options. Here's mine suggestion:

```
int len(const std::string &s, int start)
{
    /* If we are starting at the end, there's no more length */
    if(start == s.length())
        return 0;

    /* one plus whatever else... */
    return 1 + len(s, start + 1);
}
```

Assuming `str` is the string you want to get the length of, you can call it as: `len(str, 0)`

If you need to use a `const char *` version try this:

```
int len(const char *s)
{
    if((s == NULL) || (*s == 0))
        return 0; /* we ran out of string! */

    return 1 + len(s + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
int len(string s)
  {
  if (s.length()==0)
      return 0;
  else
     {
     s = s.substr(0, s.size()-1);
     return 1+(len(s));
     }
  }
```